# Appwrite init function returns "Error ENOENT"

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, command-line-interface, appwrite

I am trying to set up a cron job using Appwrite functions.
I already setup appwrite cli and every other thing works fine but when I try to create a function using "appwrite init function", I get an error directing me to open up a readme.md file that does not exist on my computer.
[image: appwrite init function image]

The thing is, when I open up my appwrite(backend) account on Chrome, I see the function I tried creating using cli.

[image: backend]

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appwrite maintainer here. We're aware of this issue and working on it as mentioned in out github issue https://github.com/appwrite/sdk-for-cli/issues/30

As a temporary workaround please use WSL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem you encounter when developing on windows,I suggest using WSL2 for your appwrite function development. Follow the steps here to [Install wsl2 on windows](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjojL21tpD4AhUJAcAKHUr7D9AQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fwindows%2Fwsl%2Finstall&usg=AOvVaw0tXqTTR7ygAK1wlSS6U77d)

After istallation, install appwrite cli with the linux install script

```
curl -sL https://appwrite.io/cli/install.sh | bash
```

Make sure you login after installation, you can then initialize your project and create your function.

everthing works perfectly for me.